# How do I make a construct to have beforeAuth only apply to certain views/functions in Laravel 4

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I have a resource in Laravel I have called artists with an ArtistsController.  I would like to add filters to some of the pages, but not all.  I know I can add a filter to all of the functions/views in the resource controller like so:

```
public function __construct()
    {
    $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('except' => array()));
    }
```

How do I add the beforeAuth filter to only a certain view/function?  I would like a user to be logged in in order to go the "index" view, but I would like a user to be able to go to the "show" pages without necessarily being logged in:

```
public function index()
    {
        $artists = Artist::all();

        return View::make('artists.index', compact('artists'))
                ->with('artists', Artist::all())
                ->with('artists_new', Artist::artists_new());
    }

public function show($id)
    {
        $artist = Artist::find($id);

        return View::make('artists.show', compact('artist'))
            ->with('fans', Fan::all());

    }
```

Is there a way to do this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this helps but you could use the **only** key instead of the **except** (if I understand your question correctly).

```
$this->beforeFilter('auth', array('only' => array('login', 'foo', 'bar')));
```

Although that would still go in the constructor.

Comment: And would I put the functions I want to be applied to this in the array?

Comment: Yes, I've added some more details to the answer. Just list the methods you wish to restrict in the array. More details on controller filters here: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#controller-filters